# Using Instagram to fetch media .Shows error "uninitialized constant Instagram"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, instagram, instagram-api, ruby-2.3

1.Installed gem "Instagram"

2.config/initializers/ instagram.rb

```
Instagram.configure do |config|
config.client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
config.client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
config.access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxXX"
end
```

3. In application_controller.rb : (app/controllers/)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
def index
@instagram = ::Instagram.user_recent_media('xxxxx', {:count => 15})
end
end
```

4. In views : (home/index.html.haml)

```
 <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
 <%= image_tag instagram.images.standard_resolution.url %>
 <% end %>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am new to ruby.

Comment: Just for clarification, have you added `require "sinatra"` and `require "instagram"` in your controller?

Comment: Where i have to add those ? i have added "require instagram" in initializers/instagram.rb

Comment: You have to use those in all controllers/models where you use its respective methods. Doing so on config file will not work.

Comment: ok..can you please tell me which link you have followed to do this? so that i can access those library files and all

Comment: Not followed any links and stuff. I am checking it out on their official github page. https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem

Comment: Ok... In that the sample application given have to be given in instagram.rb {config/initializer} ? So how to display it on the view page (.haml file)

Comment: Use the `require` in your controllers where you are using `Instagram.user_recent_media('xxxxx', {:count => 15})` aka in your application_controller.rb

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem . I have added the lib as given in this github....But now shows error "cannot load such file -- faraday" .